# How to use sentinel values different from input & sort list by feature?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I'm learning beginner python and there's one question that I'm stuck on.

The question involves asking user input for any amount of mushrooms that they have picked, entering a weight, and then sorting them according to the user input. For this, a list and a while loop is needed to append the inputs into the list.

Currently I am trying to implement a sentinel value that will stop the while loop after all of the user inputs have been entered, but setting the sentinel as "STOP" conflicts with the int() notification.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    STOP = "stop"
    mushroom = int(input("Enter a mushroom weight in grams, or STOP to end. "))
    total_list = []
    while total_list != STOP:
        total_list.append(mushroom)
        mushroom = int(input("Enter a mushroom weight in grams, or STOP to end. "))
    print(total_list)
```

The program runs well until entering "STOP", where a syntax error appears.

```
mushroom = int(input("Enter a mushroom weight in grams, or STOP to end. "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'STOP'
```

As you can see, the sentinel value STOP conflicts with my input suggestion, resulting in an error.

As for the second part of the problem, I need to sort the value inputs by weight. If everything has been done correctly, I should have a list with all the values.
What kind of code can I use in order to sort the values? 
I need to sort each integer value based on small (<100), medium (100-1000), and large (>1000), then print the results in a statement.
Am a little clueless regarding what I need to do here.

Thank you, just kind of stuck in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the error produced by trying to convert a noninteger to an integer to your advantage with `try` and `except` in Python. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for that.

Rewriting your code, you might try this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    STOP = "STOP"
    total_list = []
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = input("Enter a mushroom weight in grams, or STOP to end. ")
            total_list.append(int(user_input))  
        except ValueError:
            if user_input.strip().upper()==STOP:
                break
            else:
                print("Incorrect entry! '{}' is not an integer".format(user_input))
```

Then if you want to sort that list and put into categories, you might consider using a dictionary:

```
total_list.sort()       
di={'Small':[],'Medium':[],'Large':[]}
for e in total_list:
    key='Small' if e<100 else 'Medium' if 100<=e<=1000 else 'Large'
    di[key].append(e)

print(total_list, sum(total_list),di)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first crash is occurring because you are trying to cast "STOP" as an int. For example, if you open a python interpreter and type int("STOP") you will get the same crash. The interpreter does not know how to convert the string "STOP" to an integer. A better way might be to check if the input string can be converted to an integer with isdigit() or a try/except.

For the filtering, the easiest way would be to use a list comprehension on your lists. Something like this should work:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mushroom = None
    total_list = []
    while mushroom != "STOP":
        mushroom = input("Enter a mushroom weight in grams, or STOP to end. ")
        if mushroom.isdigit():
            total_list.append(int(mushroom))
    sorted_total_list = sorted(total_list)
    small_values = [mushroom for mushroom in total_list if mushroom < 100]
    medium_values = [mushroom for mushroom in total_list if 100 <= mushroom <= 1000]
    large_values = [mushroom for mushroom in total_list if mushroom > 1000]
    print(sorted_total_list)
    print(small_values)
    print(medium_values)
    print(large_values)
```