# How to prevent sentinel values from conflicting with input?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm learning beginner python and there's one question that I'm stuck on.

The question involves asking user input for any amount of mushrooms that they have picked, entering a weight, and then sorting them according to the user input. For this, a list and a while loop is needed to append the inputs into the list.

Here is my code so far, which works well with being able to enter all the user values, but gets stuck later on.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    total_list = []
    small = 0
    medium = 0
    large = 0
    while True:
        try:
            mushroom = int(input("Enter a mushroom weight in grams, or STOP to end. "))
            total_list.append(mushroom)
            if mushroom <= 100:
                small += 1
            elif mushroom >= 1000:
                large += 1
            else:
                medium += 1
        except STOP:
            break
    print("The weights you entered were ", total_list)
    print("There were", small, "small mushrooms,", medium, "mediums, and", large, "larges.")
```

The error occurs on line 24, where STOP conflicts with the input requirement int().

```
 mushroom = int(input("Enter a mushroom weight in grams, or STOP to end. "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'STOP'
```

How can I fix the issue to make sure that STOP is my sentinel value, and will break the while loop and print the two statements later?

Thank you.

Comment: Obviously, you need to check for 'STOP' *before* applying `int()` to the entered value.

Comment: @jasonharper would I abolish the try-except clause in that case?

Comment: You'd probably still need the `try` to handle invalid user input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use sentinel values different from input & sort list by feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244212/how-to-use-sentinel-values-different-from-input-sort-list-by-feature)